# jQuery $.post() is not working in Android WebView

Tags: android, jquery, webview, http-post

I am trying to call JavaScript from Android but `$.post()` is not working. I tried it in Postman and it is working.

> o/p: output is not defined

*MainActivity.java*

```
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/newhtml.html");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:loadjs()");
        }
    });
```

*newhtml.html*

```
<!Doctye HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadjs(){
        console.log("called");
        var json_config = {
                name: "Donald Duck",
                city: "Duckburg"
            };
        console.log("name "+json_config.name);
        console.log("city "+json_config.city)

         $.post("http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test_post.asp",json_config,function(data,status){

            console.log("data "+data);
            console.log("status "+status);
        }).fail(function(response) {
             console.log("output is "+response.responseText)
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<Body>
<div id="print_host"></div>
</Body>
</html>
```